# Qlik Sense Extenstions - Unable to reference Ref in properties panel (bug?)

Tags: qliksense

I have the following Extension Code with a properties brought out into a separate file. As per the documentation you should be able to refence `props.myTextBox` within the `layout` object, however when using the `uses: "dimensions",` to build the properties section, this is not returned, is this intended or a bug?

```js
//Properties Panel setup
define( [], function () {
    'use strict';
    // *****************************************************************************
    // Dimensions & Measures
    // *****************************************************************************
    var myTextBox = {
        ref: "props.myTextBox",
        label: "My text box",
        type: "string"
    };
    
    var dimensions = {
        uses: "dimensions",
        items: {
            myTextBox2: myTextBox, //Problem Here?
        },
    };
    var measures = {
        uses: "measures",
        min: 1,
        max:20
    };
    // *****************************************************************************
    // Appearance section
    // *****************************************************************************
    var appearanceSection = {
        uses: "settings"
    };      

    // *****************************************************************************
    // Main properties panel definition
    // Only what is defined here is returned from properties.js
    // *****************************************************************************
    return {
        type: "items",
        component: "accordion",
        items: {
            dimensions: dimensions,
            measures: measures,
            appearance: appearanceSection,
        }
    }
});
```

paint function

```js
paint: function ($element,layout) {
    console.log(layout.props.myTextBox) //Undefined?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that the issue is that the `ref` should be defined as: `ref: "qDef.myTextBox"`

```js
var myTextBox = {
    ref: "qDef.myTextBox",
    label: "My text box",
    type: "string"
};
```

Once this is added then you can access `myTextBox` property in the `layout` for each dimension

[image: layout]

**P.S.** After making a change in the definitions make sure to re-add the extension object on the sheet.

Comment: But I want the text box under the dimension section, not under appearances, that i got to work but not when i wanted it under Dimensions instead, thats the problem.

Comment: Perfect, thankyou, is there documentation on this anywhere? I can't seem to find any?

Comment: Found a thread in the Qlik Community. Someone explained there that `qDef` have to be used if the property is added to the dimensions/measures. Which makes sense, since this property will be part of the hypercube calculations.